# Java: Is it possible to take a GUI Panel and output it into a picture?

Tags: java

So I have this chart that's a little special. Kind of like an XY plot of points but my boss wanted to look like a bunch of boxes rather than dots connected by lines. And I basically made a chart using gridlayout and a whole bunch of cells that I'll be colouring in black or white depending on the data.

Now he sorta wants it to be outputted to a image file. Is there any way to save a Panel into a picture? He wants to display not only the data but also save a visual representation of the data into an image file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to save a Panel into
>   a picture?

[Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Graphics context which paints to an image. This technique is often used with animations to prepare drawings offline and swap them in place to avoid artifacts.

Typically you can use the same paint methos as used to paint your canvas.

[Here are more details](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Imageofflinerendering.htm)